# How to upload multiple files with caption for each file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I want to upload multiple files in ASP.NET.

I also want caption to be saved in database for each file.

I found many articles on multiple file upload but was not able to found multiple file upload with caption for each file.
Eg. I want file upload control and respective textbox for that file upload control in which user can enter caption.
I also want to see uploaded files in edit mode.

Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask Instead of saying thanks we upvote, instead of writing signatures we fill a profile.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
    <input type="file" runat="server" id="txtFile1">
    <input type="text" runat="server" id="txtCap1">
    <br>
    <input type="file" runat="server" id="txtFile2">
    <input type="text" runat="server" id="txtCap2">
</form>
```

Server Side(C#)

```
UploadFile(txtFile1, txtCap1);

UploadFile(txtFile2, txtCap2);

private void UploadFile(HtmlInputFile txtFile, HtmlInputText txtCaption)
{
    string fileName=  txtFile.PostedFile.FileName; 
    string  caption=txtCaption.Value;
    txtFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(fileName);
}
```